# Score is not being registered by GameCenter

Tags: ios, game-center, leaderboard

The Game is on, it is registered to Sandbox and yet cannot see a trace of registered data on GameCenter App.

The Game isn't available yet at AppStore, but I can see the game on GameCenter App.

The process is simple. I have set a GameKitHelper and it looks like it do the right thing.

Please take a look:

GameKitHelper.h

```
//   Include the GameKit framework
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

//   Protocol to notify external
//   objects when Game Center events occur or
//   when Game Center async tasks are completed
@protocol GameKitHelperProtocol<NSObject>

-(void) onScoresSubmitted:(bool)success;

@end


@interface GameKitHelper : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign)
id<GameKitHelperProtocol> delegate;

// This property holds the last known error
// that occured while using the Game Center API's
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSError* lastError;

+ (id) sharedGameKitHelper;

// Player authentication, info
-(void) authenticateLocalPlayer;

// Scores
-(void) submitScore:(int64_t)score
           category:(NSString*)category;

@end
```

GameKitHelper.m

```
#import "GameKitHelper.h"

@interface GameKitHelper ()
<GKGameCenterControllerDelegate> {
    BOOL _gameCenterFeaturesEnabled;
}
@end

@implementation GameKitHelper

-(void) submitScore:(int64_t)score
           category:(NSString*)category {
    //1: Check if Game Center
    //   features are enabled
    if (!_gameCenterFeaturesEnabled) {
        CCLOG(@"Player not authenticated");
        return;
    }

    //2: Create a GKScore object
    GKScore* gkScore =
    [[GKScore alloc]
     initWithCategory:category];

    //3: Set the score value
    gkScore.value = score;

    //4: Send the score to Game Center
    [gkScore reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(NSError* error) {

         [self setLastError:error];

         BOOL success = (error == nil);

         if ([_delegate
              respondsToSelector:
              @selector(onScoresSubmitted:)]) {

             [_delegate onScoresSubmitted:success];
         }
     }];
}

#pragma mark Singleton stuff

+(id) sharedGameKitHelper {
    static GameKitHelper *sharedGameKitHelper;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedGameKitHelper =
        [[GameKitHelper alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedGameKitHelper;
}

#pragma mark Player Authentication

-(void) authenticateLocalPlayer {

    GKLocalPlayer* localPlayer =
    [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler =
    ^(UIViewController *viewController,
      NSError *error) {

        [self setLastError:error];

        if ([CCDirector sharedDirector].isPaused)
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];

        if (localPlayer.authenticated) {
            _gameCenterFeaturesEnabled = YES;
        } else if(viewController) {
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
            [self presentViewController:viewController];
        } else {
            _gameCenterFeaturesEnabled = NO;
        }
    };
}

#pragma mark Property setters

-(void) setLastError:(NSError*)error {
    _lastError = [error copy];
    if (_lastError) {
        NSLog(@"GameKitHelper ERROR: %@", [[_lastError userInfo]
                                           description]);
    }
}

#pragma mark UIViewController stuff

-(UIViewController*) getRootViewController {
    return [UIApplication
            sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
}

-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController*)vc {
    UIViewController* rootVC = [self getRootViewController];
    [rootVC presentViewController:vc animated:YES
                       completion:nil];
}
@end
```

First of all I call the following method for player's authentication:

```
[[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper]
         authenticateLocalPlayer];
```

Then, when the level is done a call this second method:

```
[[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper]
             submitScore:(int64_t)numberMoves
             category:kMovesLevel1LeaderboardCategory];
```

The LeaderBoard ID is equal to the iTunesConnect. This piece of code I got from http://www.raywenderlich.com/23189/whats-new-with-game-center-in-ios-6, which is 6.0 targeted. But I didn't see any big deal so far.

What am I missing?
Thank you!

Comment: And yes, I have already waited more than 24 hours. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to enable the leaderboard in iTunes Connect?

For the app in question:

1. Click **View Details** --> Scroll to bottom --> click the **Game Center switch** (toggles between disabled/enabled).
2. Add the leaderboard(s) you want to use.